# Best Way to Display Progress Bar For Long SQL Transactions?

Tags: asp.net

So I have C# function that's gathering data results and images and uploading them to the SQL Database.

What I'd like to do is create a progress bar showing the progress through this function(by like incrementing the bar `1/NumOfLoops` each pass of the outer most loop).

I was hoping to just use a DIV with changing width as my progress bar, stuck in an update panel.

The issue of course is triggering the update panel to update.

Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I would suggest just showing a "thinking" GIF inside of an `UpdateProgress` control.  Building the logic to accurately predict the remaining time left in an operation is something even Microsoft didn't incorporate into Windows until Win7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but you may not the like the solution I link you to, because it involves using an iFrame.

Read [Easy incremental status updates for long requests](http://encosia.com/easy-incremental-status-updates-for-long-requests/) for details on how to use JavaScript to create an iFrame that hosts your long running process `.aspx` page and then have that page stream back its progress.

Note: In the example, the progress values are streamed back and reported via the text of the button, which is disabled while the long-running process does its work.